# Identify which element was clicked, among a set of similar elements, in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page which contains posts.

Post is defined by:

```html
<div class="post">
  <p>...</p>
  <a href="#" class="post-react">Like</a>
  <input type="hidden" name="post-id" value="[postid]">
</div>
```

A single page can contain many such posts.
When I click "Like", how do I detect which post element's "Like" button was clicked?

I tried this in jquery:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.post-react').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON('...', {
        post_id: $('input[name="post-id"]', this).val()
      }, function(data) {
         //something
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('input[name="post-id"]', this)` is looking for an input that is a descendant of `this` but the input is not inside the `<a>`, it is a sibling

Use `next()` or `siblings()` instead or traverse to the `post` and use `find()`

```
post_id: $(this).next().val()
// OR
post_id: $(this).siblings('input[name="post-id"]').val()
// OR
post_id: $(this).closest('.post').find('input[name="post-id"]').val()
```

Note that `bind()` is a very old method that is superseded by `on()`